# Space Invaders: Loading Images

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame

I'm trying to make Space Invaders as a project, I've watched videos on creating it and I have done quite a bit.

I've played around with it a lot, but there's always that one thing that goes wrong which messes up the entire thing.

This is my first post here, I'm not quite sure how to do this... let's see...

I keep facing this error, and it's not budging:

```
C:/Users/Dell/PycharmProjects/Tutorial(2)/main.py:198: DeprecationWarning: an integer is required (got type float).  Implicit conversion to integers using __int__ is deprecated, and may be removed in a future version of Python.
  pygame.draw.rect(window, (0, 255, 0), (
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Dell/PycharmProjects/Tutorial(2)/main.py", line 415, in <module>
    main_menu()
  File "C:/Users/Dell/PycharmProjects/Tutorial(2)/main.py", line 410, in main_menu
    main()
  File "C:/Users/Dell/PycharmProjects/Tutorial(2)/main.py", line 377, in main
    boss.shoot()
  File "C:/Users/Dell/PycharmProjects/Tutorial(2)/main.py", line 90, in shoot
    laser = Laser(self.x - 20, self.y, self.laser_img)
  File "C:/Users/Dell/PycharmProjects/Tutorial(2)/main.py", line 109, in __init__
    self.mask = pygame.mask.from_surface(self.img)
TypeError: argument 1 must be pygame.Surface, not None
```

Can anyone help me fix it? I'm not sure what to do here.

Comment: You specifically set `self.laser_img` to `None` in your `Ship` class.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look at this line here

```
            boss = Boss(random.randrange(340, 360), random.randrange(-700, -100))
```

This is how you are instantiating your Boss

Now look at how you defined the **init** of your Boss class

```
 def __init__(self, x, y, health=200):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.health = health
        self.ship_img = None
        self.laser_img = None
        self.lasers = []
        self.cool_down_counter = 0
```

Notice that `self.laser_img = None`.

Now notice the error you have:

```py
    laser = Laser(self.x - 20, self.y, self.laser_img)
```

Your 3rd argument is None. Now look at the next part of your error:

```
        self.mask = pygame.mask.from_surface(self.img)
```

`self.img` is actually `None` that is why you are getting an error.

Comment: Oh my god, thanks, I feel so dumb right now. I spent way too long searching for that error.

Comment: It happens! Some advice is to go through your stacktrace step by step from your error and ask yourself, "What could happen at this step to get the error?" and adding print statements to debug would help. Also, please accept my response as an answer if it answered the question.